# MuleSoft ForEach Parallel loop. Unnecessary message with garbled characters in the output

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mojibake

In my flow in Mule 4, I iterate over multiple files to get data from them and transform them to json. I use a parallel ForEach component to do this. Here are the expected outputs from both of these calls:

result 1:

```
{
"plant": "CD909837289",
"serial": "SRF",
"product": "CMNPSD"
},
{
 "plant": "CD909837290",
 "serial": "SFG",
 "product": "CMNHSA"
}
```

result 2:

```
{
"plant": "CD909837296",
"serial": "SFG",
"product": "ERTYUI"
},
{
 "plant": "CD909837297",
 "serial": "SVH",
 "product": "SDFGHJ"
}
```

When I make the call I get these outputs combined together however, I also get the below message with garbled characters mixed with them:

```
    ��srjava.util.ArrayListx����a�IsizexpwsrRorg.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.DefaultMessageBuilder$MessageImplementationeJ蹨��L
inboundMaptLjava/util/Map;LoutboundMapq~LtypedAttributest*Lorg/mule/runtime/api/metadata/TypedValue;xpsr3org.mule.runtime.api.util.CaseInsensitiveMapWrappervrD=wny3LbaseMapq~xpsrjava.util.HashMap���`�F
loadFactorI thresholdxp?@wxsq~sq~?@wxsr(org.mule.runtime.api.metadata.TypedValue�i�Қ,��LdataTypet(Lorg/mule/runtime/api/metadata/DataType;LvaluetLjava/lang/Object;xpsr6org.mule.runtime.core.internal.metadata.SimpleDataType�Jd�~�Z
streamTypeLmimeTypet)Lorg/mule/runtime/api/metadata/MediaType;LtypetLjava/lang/Class;xpsr'org.mule.runtime.api.metadata.MediaTypeͬU�q�S�ZdefinedInAppLparamsq~LprimaryTypetLjava/lang/String;LsubTypeq~xpsrjava.util.Collections$EmptyMapY6�Z���xpt*q~pxvr/org.mule.extension.file.api.LocalFileAttributesJ�5��Z    directoryZregularFileJsizeZsymbolicLinkLcreationTimetLjava/time/LocalDateTime;LlastAccessTimeq~LlastModifiedTimeq~xr9org.mule.extension.file.common.api.AbstractFileAttributes���$pLfileNameq~Lpathq~xpsq~tproduct-date.csvt=/Users/dbien_local/Downloads/DATAFORSCORPION/product-date.csvesr
java.time.Ser�]��"H�xpw
��xsq~!w
�*�xsq~!w
��xw��������xz��[
  {
    "plant": "CD909837289",
    "serial": "SRF",
    "product": "CMNPSD"
  },
  {
    "plant": "CD909837290",
    "serial": "SFG",
    "product": "CMNHSA"
  }
```

I get the same message before each result. How can I get rid of the above text and get the expected output only?

EDIT:
Below is the XML of the flow:

```
<file:config name="File_Config" doc:name="File Config" doc:id="45e5b346-2497-4422-961b-a04bb5a7bf80" >
    <file:connection workingDir="/Users/dbien_local/Downloads/DATAFORSCORPION" />
</file:config>
<flow name="get-data-ifFlow" doc:id="8d6b11ec-2a24-49b4-82b4-195816aeb8e5" >
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="8937d90f-75f7-43d0-bf20-02f70f9b2073" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/data"/>
<parallel-foreach doc:name="Parallel For Each" doc:id="50ca63de-9004-4a52-97f8-9935425c2763" collection='#[["date", "product"]]'>
        <file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="f3fbadf3-2716-47c6-803b-90edefff67a3" config-ref="File_Config" path='#["/Users/dbien_local/Downloads/data/product-" ++ payload ++ ".csv"]' />
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="cf7d4f97-2144-4a49-958c-323e26b8b00e">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
    plant: payload01.plant,
    serial: payload01.serial,
    product: payload01.product
}]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
            
</parallel-foreach>
```

There are only two components in the loop. One reads the data from a csv file and then a transform message component transforms it to JSON. I have absolutely no idea where that java message comes from.

Comment: Please add your flow as XML in text to the question and indicates where in the flow that value happens.

Comment: Just FYI it looks like your inputs are JSON arrays but are missing the outer brackets.

Comment: @aled thanks man. I have added XML configuration to the original question.

Comment: I have tested this now and I see that message is added as soon as the loop start. Even reading data only adds that message to the output/

Comment: There is no logger in the snippet of the flow. How are you seeing that output exactly? And what is the exact version of Mule 4, including cumulative patching if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aled mentioned, you are seeing the serialized java object. You can add a transform message after parallel-foreach to get the JSON message.

To get the list of payloads, use the following script in a transform message or set payload.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.payload
```

Comment: This was it. Thank you. I couldn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the Payload type before merging it? Something like this:

```
((write(payload.message, "application/json"))
```

Comment: Tried this now, I'm getting the same results. I have no idea where that text comes from.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a serialization of Java objects. Because there is not enough information in the question for a more concrete answer I will make an educated guess and assume that you are seeing a message, or message list instead of the payload that you expect to see. Remember that the parallel foreach, unlike the standard foreach, returns a list of messages, not a list of payloads. The [message contains the payload in addition to attributes](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/about-mule-event). You need to take only the payload from each message of the list.

Also try to use the latest release of Mule 4 and if possible the latest cumulative patching to avoid known issues of previous releases.